# ClassNotFoundException in spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I am getting class not found exception while using application context in Spring Framework
Here is my code...

```
String files[] = new String[]{"car.xml","engine.xml"};
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(files);
```

---

```
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@17a7cec2: startup date [Thu May 11 00:42:13 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.customizeBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:218)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at ABC.main(ABC.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)enter code enter code herehere
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)``
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Hi @rupesh-kumar, welcome on Stack Overflow. It would be nice to complete your post with an actual question, i.e. you are getting this exception and ... ? What about it ? Looking forward to your updated question.

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle for building your dependencies? What is the Spring jar dependency you are using ?

Comment: No., Neither maven nor gradle

Comment: I am using Secondary Data Type Dependency Injection,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your stacktrace pointing this:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor

Add the spring-asm jar file in classpath or pom file(if using maven ).

Comment: i'm not using maven